# About finite moment problem

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, algebraic-geometry, moment-problem

My question is, given a real random variable $u$, then can we find a discrete random variable $\xi$  with finite possible values, such that $u$ and $\xi$ have the same first $2k$ moments?

According to my intuition, it seems like that there exists an even distribution
$$P(\xi=x_i)=\frac{1}{k+1},\ k=1,\dots,n$$
satisfies the requirement. But I have no idea about how to prove it.

The key point is that how to decide whether the following equations has at least one solution over $\mathbb{C}$,
$$\begin{align}
x_1+\dots+x_n&=n\cdot\mathrm{E}u,\\
 &\ \ \vdots\\
x_1^{2k}+\dots+x_n^{2k}&=n\cdot\mathrm{E}u^{2k}.
\end{align}$$

If it actually exists a solution, we can prove the solution is real by using Hankel matrix.

Is there any conclusion in algebraic-geometry can be used to state the existence of the solution?

Comment: Look up the Newton relations: your equation is equivalent to saying that the $x_i$ are roots of some polynomial function whose coefficients are polynomials in the moments of $u$.

Comment: The system of equations is similar to that of the Hilbert-Kamke problem.